# Find a list of @ statements in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm using this tutorial: http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee/ejb

I keep seeing words prefixed with @.  Is there somewhere I can find a list of these and read about what they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are known as annotations. Read the [Java Tutorial article about them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) for an introduction. To quote that article:

> Annotations provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. They have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.
>
> Annotations have a number of uses, among them:
>
> - **Information for the compiler** — Annotations can be used by the compiler
>   to detect errors or suppress warnings.
> - **Compiler-time and deployment-time processing** — Software tools can process annotation
>   information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.
> - **Runtime processing** — Some annotations are available to be examined at runtime.
>   Annotations can be applied to a program's declarations of classes,
>   fields, methods, and other program elements.

After reading that article, you can move on to [this reference of EJB annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/annotations.html), which should explain the annotations featured in that particular tutorial.